# sankey diagram can't be displayed in powerBI by python plotly lib

Tags: python, powerbi, sankey-diagram

1. I have below scripts with python

> ```
> import pandas as pd
> import chart_studio.plotly as py
> import plotly.graph_objects as go
> labelListTemp1 = list(set(dataset.source.values))
> labelListTemp2 = list(set(dataset.target.values))
> labelList = labelListTemp1 + labelListTemp2
> sankey_node = list(dict.fromkeys(labelList))
> fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey( node = dict( pad=15, 
>                                              thickness=20, 
>                                              line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
>                                              label = labelList,
>                                              color = "blue" ),
>                                               link = dict(source = dataset.source.apply(lambda x: labelList.index(x)),
>                                                           target = dataset.target.apply(lambda x: labelList.index(x)),
>                                                           value = dataset.value))])
>
> fig.show()
> ```

2. Then I enable python visual in powerBI, and then drag-and-drop source, target and value into 'Values' section.
3. Then I run the python script in step1
4. But the sankey chart doesn't displayed in powerBI.  the code open a browser and display the sankey chart in the browser, which is not what I want. please refer to below screenshot.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Expected result: I want the sankey chart displayed inside powerBI, so I can publish the chart and send it to team members.**

Any expert please help take a look what's wrong with my code?

Thanks,
Cherie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find an anwser from a post with "import plotly.io as pio" first, and then replace fig.show() with below code

```
pio.write_image(fig, 'perfUXRGoal.png').
```

with above code, it's a static image displayed inside powerBI, instead of interactive html chart.